# How to limit SSM based on user starting the command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-cli, aws-ssm

I have an EC2 that I am connecting to using the AWS Systems manager, the EC2 has a role of AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore attached and I am able to use ssm startSession from the CLI.

Without adding permissions to the users themselves am I able to limit which users are allowed to initiate a session to the EC2s?

I have tried adding a second policy to the EC2s where I block access to ssm:StartSession (which works when I apply it with no condition) with a condition containing aws.userid and aws:ssmmessages:session-id but neither of these blocked access.

I am using federated users in this account.

Below is an example of the most recent policy attempting to block access to that specific email but not others (which does not work).

```
const myPolicy = new ManagedPolicy(this, "sendAndBlockPoicy", {
  statements: [
    new PolicyStatement({
      sid: "AllowSendCommand",
      effect: Effect.ALLOW,
      resources: [`arn:aws:ec2:${Aws.REGION}:${Aws.ACCOUNT_ID}:*`],
      actions: ["ssm:SendCommand"],
    }),
    new PolicyStatement({
      sid: "blockUsers",
      effect: Effect.DENY,
      resources: ["*"],
      actions: ["ssm:*", "ssmmessages:*", "ec2messages:*"],
      conditions: {
        StringLike: {
          "aws:ssmmessages:session-id":
            "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV:me@email.com",
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
});

const managedSSMPolicy = ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName(
  "AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore",
);

const role = new Role(this, 'ec2Role', {
    assumedBy: new ServicePrincipal('ec2.amazonaws.com')
    managedPolicies: [managedSSMPolicy, myPolicy ]
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the policy document?

Comment: Also, since it is an instance role, I don't think `aws.userid` will work. The permissions are attached to an instance, not any IAM user.

Comment: @Marcin Yeah I think I was being hopeful. the event grabbed from cloud trail had the structure containing "event.userIdentity.principalId" which contained my user but adding this to the condition didn't seem to work either.